# MySql Query for Wordpress

Tags: plugins, php, mysql

I need to count the number of value 1 from wp_ul_locked on wp_usermeta i try this code

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE 'meta_key' LIKE 'wp_ul_locked'");
```

or

`$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = '1'")`;

or

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->usermeta LIKE 'wp_ul_locked' WHERE meta_value = '1'");
```

but return empty or error

[image: example of table]

Where is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE `meta_key` = 'wp_ul_locked' AND `meta_value` = '1'");
```